# Using Sage Pay iFrame method ,for customer click the url to complete the payment,how can I generate the iFrame URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, opayo

Here is the issue:
My website use the Sage Pay iFrame method for customer to finished their payment ,but I don't know how to generate the payment URL, which can be clicked by customer redirect to Sage Pay to finish the payment .

The URL is what I need, or How to generate this URL.

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/JeremySkinner/SagePayMvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [SagePay API documentation here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/server-inframe-integration-documents) which will take you through how to create the request to SagePay in order to receive the nextUrl, specifically [Appendix A1 and Appendix A2](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/12246/download-document/SERVER_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_010814.pdf?token=5tYHjDzqDnsfUdjPiNJHUKAW3RyTZ95ygDF_49Tr-pY) - as this is your request and response object for the payment registration. Basically the process works like this:

- You send the request object (in A1 of the appendix) to SagePay's server - you will need to read the relevant sections of the linked PDF for this.
- They response with the response object (A2), of which one of the properties is NextUrl.
- You can then either present the url to the user to click on, or a better solution is to return a page to the user, using the NextUrl value as the src of the iframe in the page - something like

-

```
return View("Payment", new SagePayView { nextUrl = sagePayResponse.NextUrl });
```

And your payment view:

```
<h2>Secure Payment by SagePay</h2>
<iframe src="@Model.nextUrl" width="600", height="600" frameborder="0" border="0" style="margin-left:15px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you guys…the document is great helpful.